# dramatically increased vs increased dramatically

Tags: verbs, british-english, adverbs, ielts, academic-writing

In a very formal writing such as IELTS writing task 1, can I use both of these?

```
>dramatically increased
>increased dramatically
```

Example:

> Product prices have increased dramatically in the last few years.

> Product prices have dramatically increased in the last few years.

I mean, I am confused that if there is any rule such as adverb can not be placed before/after the verb. ( I have found many confusing answers on the internet, please answer it if you are 100% sure about it) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct with difference in emphasis.

> In English, an adverb typically stays close to the verb it modifies. ***The writer’s desired emphasis determines adverb placement*** (e.g., “*walked sadly*” or “*sadly walked*”). ([Grammar.book](https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/adjectives-adverbs/adjectives-and-adverbs-when-to-use-ly/))

In

> Product prices have *increased* ***dramatically*** in the last few years.

the emphasis falls on *dramatically*, whereas in

> Product prices have *dramatically* ***increased*** in the last few years.

you are focusing on conveying the information carried by *increased*.

Note that ***dramatically*** is a very... "dramatic" word which does tend to attract attention to itself. It is perhaps the reason why [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=increased%20dramatically%2Cdramatically%20increased&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cincreased%20dramatically%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdramatically%20increased%3B%2Cc0) shows that the use of ***increased dramatically*** is more frequent.